# Windows App Certification Kit does not support 8.0 XAP Packages, please upgrade your XAP package and re-run it against WACK

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, windows-10, windows-store

I have created a Phonegap app for Windows Phone and it was failing at time of uploading to Windows Store. On the website they recommend to use Windows App Certification Kit to validate it locally. When I run it I get this error:

```
Windows App Certification Kit does not support 8.0 XAP Packages,
please upgrade your XAP package and re-run it against WACK.
```

How can I set up Phonegap to create a more upgraded version of XAP?

Errors on Windows Store started when I added this to the config.xml:

```
<gap:config-file platform="winphone" parent="/Deployment" mode="replace">
        <Languages xmlns=""> 
           <Language code="es-ES"/>
        </Languages>
        <DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="es-ES" />
    </gap:config-file>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the windows phone 8 sdk app certification toolkit.  I think you were using one for the windows rt version of the phone project which expects an appx file instead

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that Phonegap cannot create Windows 10 phone apps?

Comment: You can create windows 10 apps with the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova